# Cannot Install Django on Windows 7 using Pip

Tags: django, python-3.x, virtualenv

Using Windows 7. Installed Python 3.4.2 (previously had 2.7.x and uninstalled that before installing 3.4). Made a virtualenv and then tried to install Django and getting an error:

```
(myvenv) C:\Users\user1\djangogirls>pip install Django==1.7.1
Downloading/unpacking Django==1.7.1
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Django==1.7.1
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for Django==1.7.1
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\user1\pip\pip.log
```

Here's the log, and help appreciated:

---

> ```
> C:\Users\user1\djangogirls\myvenv\Scripts\pip run on 11/24/14 13:33:01 Downloading/unpacking Django==1.7.1   Getting page
> ```
>
> https://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/   Could not fetch URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/: connection error:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /simple/Django/ (Caused by : [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed)   Will skip URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/ when looking for download links
>   for Django==1.7.1   Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
>   Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: connection error:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /simple/ (Caused by :
>   [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed)   Will skip URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for
>   Django==1.7.1   Cannot fetch index base URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/   URLs to search for versions for
>   Django==1.7.1:   * https://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/1.7.1   *
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/   Getting page
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/1.7.1   Could not fetch URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/1.7.1: connection error:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /simple/Django/1.7.1 (Caused by : [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed)   Will skip URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/1.7.1 when looking for download
>   links for Django==1.7.1   Getting page
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/   Could not fetch URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/: connection error:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: /simple/Django/ (Caused by : [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed)   Will skip URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/ when looking for download links
>   for Django==1.7.1   Could not find any downloads that satisfy the
>   requirement Django==1.7.1 Cleaning up...   Removing temporary dir
>   C:\Users\user1\djangogirls\myvenv\build... No distributions at all
>   found for Django==1.7.1 Exception information: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\user1\djangogirls\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py",
>   line 122, in main
>           status = self.run(options, args)   File "C:\Users\user1\djangogirls\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py",
>   line 278, in run
>           requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)   File
>   "C:\Users\user1\djangogirls\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line
>   1177, in prepare_files
>           url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)   File
>   "C:\Users\user1\djangogirls\myvenv\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py",
>   line 277, in find_requirement
>           raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req) pip.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No distributions at
>   all found for Django==1.7.1

Comment: since 1.7.1 is the current version, just running `pip install Django` should do the trick

Comment: Same thing happened with just "Django".

Comment: I turned off the windows firewall and it installed OK. I don't know whether it's just a slow connection at first and it coincidently worked now or if the firewall was blocking some aspect of PIP. Will know more when I try PIP more... Don't know if I should cite this as an "answer".

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that you have a connection error with pip. Please check your Internet connection first. If your connection is okay, you can try other mirror when use pip, for example:

```
pip install -i http://mirrors-url-here/simple Django
```

Ref:

http://jacobian.org/writing/when-pypi-goes-down/